# Software testing and non-functional properties

Tags: non-functional

Do you think that software testing is good for non-functional properties?
What are the non-functional properties that could be evaluated through software testing? Security, accessibility, usability, energy consumption...?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  Are you asking whether *automated* test is good for those things?  Or whether software *testers* are capable of testing non-functional things?  Or something else?

Comment: Not the testers, but if the Testing is capable to testing non-function things

Answer (score 2):

Nonfunctional requirements generally support all users in that they describe the business standards and the business environment, as well as the overall user's experience, therefore, software testing is very essential for non-functional properties also.

In non-functional testing the quality characteristics of the component or system is tested. Non-functional refers to aspects of the software that may not be related to a specific function or user action such as scalability or security. E.g. How many people can log in at once? Non-functional testing is also performed at all levels like functional testing.

Non-functional testing includes:

Usability testing,
    Efficiency testing,
    Maintainability testing,
    Portability testing,
    Baseline testing,
    Compliance testing,
    Documentation testing,
    Endurance testing,
    Load testing,
    Performance testing,
    Compatibility testing,Security testing,
    Scalability testing,
    Volume testing,
    Stress testing,
    Recovery testing,

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm getting the opinion of several people. You talk about kinds of testing that I don't knew like Endurance and Documentation. It's good to know non-functional software testing is an important topic.

Comment: apologies for my bad english

Comment: Endurance testing is also known as Soak testing.
Endurance testing involves testing a system with a significant load extended over a significant period of time, to discover how the system behaves under sustained use. For example, in software testing, a system may behave exactly as expected when tested for 1 hour but when the same system is tested for 3 hours, problems such as memory leaks cause the system to fail or behave randomly.

Answer (score 0):

It is totally depends on your software/website and requirement also.  But it is really important and beneficial that we choose and perform non-functional testing techniques as per our need.

Basically no-function testing includes following :

1 - Load testing

2 - stress testing

3 - portability testing

4 - reliability testing

5 - usability testing

6 - maintainability testing

7 - Recovery testing

and there are some others.

Basically non-functional is the
testing of “how” the system works.

Comment: “how” the system works as opposed to what ?

Comment: It means behavior of system.

Comment: depends on the requirements and deadlines of the project

Comment: deadlines influences everythink :)

Answer (score 0):

ISTQB describes non-functional tests as following:

Non-functional testing includes, but is not limited to, performance testing, load testing, stress testing, usability testing, maintainability testing, reliability testing and portability testing. It is the testing of "how" the system works.

Comment: I agree, reading up on the ISTQB Foundation course will help you .